# Conservation of energy in quasar outflows?

Tags: magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, astrophysics, space-expansion, quasars

I found [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/321630) about the behavior of quasar outflows in cosmology and how they can create a magnetic field.

In section 2.1.4., the authors say that when a quasar produces a "wave" or an outflow, the material will be emitted with energy coming from both the quasar itself and the Hubble flow of the expansion of the Universe itself.

Then, is energy conserved in this case? Wouldn't the Hubble expansion be adding "new" energy to the system according to the article?

I am aware that conservation of energy is difficult to define in General Relativity and at cosmological scales, but the thing is that I am not sure if I am misundersting something in this model or if conservation of energy does not indeed apply in this case

Comment: Since energy is generally not conserved in the context of an expanding universe, why would it be noteworthy for it not to be conserved in this case?

Comment: @ACuriousMind the thing is that I am not sure if I am misundersting something in this model or if indeed conservation of energy does not apply in this case